# org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to stop component [SingleSignOn[]]

Tags: apache, tomcat8, josso

I am using Apache Tomcat 8.5.12 with JOSSO single sign on .
After configuration I can not start the tomcat server and I get this error.
Everything is well configured.
Does anyone have an idea that can help me to start the server ?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUsSX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache Tomcat 8.5 doesn't play nice with the JOSSO Agent for Apache Tomcat 8 as the former has changed the approach for hooking into the event bus. Therefore, an ad-hoc SSO agent is needed, included in an early access release of JOSSO 1.8.12, available here for download : https://github.com/atricore/josso1/releases/tag/1.8.12-rc1-release

A binary distribution is included, hence there's no need to build from the source.

In order to install it, make sure to manually replace the "old" agent artifacts - namely the JOSSO Agent for Tomcat 8 JAR files - with the ones that ship with 1.8.12 RC1.

As far as configuration is concerned, the following changes in the *$CATALINA_HOME/lib/josso-agent-config.xml* descriptor need to be applied for the JOSSO Agent for Apache Tomcat 8.5 to be instantiated.

From:

```xml
<bean class="org.josso.tc80.agent.CatalinaSSOAgent" name="josso-tc80-agent">
```

To:

```xml
<bean class="org.josso.tc85.agent.CatalinaSSOAgent" name="josso-tc85-agent">
```

As of the JOSSO server component, there is no need to perform any upgrade nor configuration change.